# Transferring data from Salesforce MC to GCS

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-export, google-analytics, data-extract

My company asked me to find a way to transfer a data extract from Salesforce Marketing Cloud in a Google Cloud Storage bucket, so that they can bring it into Data Studio or Analytics.

I've done some searches and I'm still not sure if that's actually possible, I only found out about the Analytics 360 integration. Should I consider using a third party software?

Comment: Remember to mark my answer as accepted if it has been helpful

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to connect a Google Cloud Storage bucket to MC, as the only methods available for GCS are ([as per documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/gcs-buckets)):

> Write and read files from Cloud Storage buckets by using the gsutil
> command-line tool or the Cloud Storage API.

As MC only supports FTP/SFTP as a File Location, you will need to put an FTP server between MC and your GCS. There are few threads on SO describing how to establish an FTP server which writes to GCS, e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43486480/ftp-to-google-storage - but this indeed requires some significant development.